# Reading bytes from file into memory

Tags: go, arrays

I am using `bufio` to append byte arrays to a file. When I use `cat` on it I get:

```
[176 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 57 12 127 47 4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 215 136 47 0 64 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 57 0 97 0 53 0 52 0 100 0 98 0 99 0 52 0 98 0 100 0 100 0 49 0 54 0 99 0 49 0 97 0 49 0 57 0 56 0 48 0 52 0 55 0 53 0 49 0 100 0 49 0 49 0 51 0 99 0 52 0 52 0 98 0 24 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 83 0 111 0 109 0 101 0 32 0 99 0 108 0 105 0 101 0 110 0 116 0 0 0 36 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 83 0 111 0 109 0 101 0 32 0 111 0 116 0 104 0 101 0 114 0 32 0 112 0 97 0 114 0 116 0 110 0 101 0 114 0][176 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 162 127 47 4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 215 136 47 0 64 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 57 0 97 0 53 0 52 0 100 0 98 0 99 0 52 0 98 0 100 0 100 0 49 0 54 0 99 0 49 0 97 0 49 0 57 0 56 0 48 0 52 0 55 0 53 0 49 0 100 0 49 0 49 0 51 0 99 0 52 0 52 0 98 0 24 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 83 0 111 0 109 0 101 0 32 0 99 0 108 0 105 0 101 0 110 0 116 0 0 0 36 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 83 0 111 0 109 0 101 0 32 0 111 0 116 0 104 0 101 0 114 0 32 0 112 0 97 0 114 0 116 0 110 0 101 0 114 0][176 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 35 200 127 47 4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 215 136 47 0 64 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 57 0 97 0 53 0 52 0 100 0 98 0 99 0 52 0 98 0 100 0 100 0 49 0 54 0 99 0 49 0 97 0 49 0 57 0 56 0 48 0 52 0 55 0 53 0 49 0 100 0 49 0 49 0 51 0 99 0 52 0 52 0 98 0 24 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 83 0 111 0 109 0 101 0 32 0 99 0 108 0 105 0 101 0 110 0 116 0 0 0 36 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 83 0 111 0 109 0 101 0 32 0 111 0 116 0 104 0 101 0 114 0 32 0 112 0 97 0 114 0 116 0 110 0 101 0 114 0]
```

So arrays of bytes. Now I want to read the file into memory, so I use:

```
content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
```

But when I display the `content` variable I get a completely different output than the contents of the file (and one array instead of many). What's wrong?

Comment: Without a minimal working example of your code we won't be able to help you much.

Comment: `iotuil.ReadFile` just reads the bytes from the file, it doesn't know how to interpret those as a data structure other than `[]byte`

Answer (score 0):

You wrote it wrong to the file. Its human readable format, should be binary.

My guess you used something like `fmt.Fprintln(file, byte_slice)` or variants.

It must be `fmt.Fprintf(file, "%s", byte_slice)` or similar.

Please, show us code how you write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

So what think is happening is that the content inside of that file is a string. When you pull it out of the file it converts that string to bytes. What you need to do is convert those bytes to a string before you append to the file and then convert them back when you pull from the file

https://play.golang.org/p/PyBXAU9rVW